# How to pick a random function from a predefined set?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have these functions defined:

```
function playZoomout() {
// do things
}
function playZoomin() {
// do things
}
function playPanright() {
// do things
}
function playPanleft() {
// do things
}
```

and am running this every four seconds:

```
var timer = setInterval(playZoomout,4000);
```

How can I replace "playZoomout" with a randomly selected function picked from the ones defined above? I'm looking for a jQuery or plain javascript solution.

Comment: Put the functions in an array and [pick a random element from that array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4550505/218196).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of function references, then fetch an element randomly from the array and invoke it.

```
var fns = [playZoomout, playZoomin, playPanright, playPanleft]
setInterval(function () {
    fns[Math.floor(Math.random() * fns.length)]();
}, 1000)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6TxnH/)

Comment: Perhaps calling `fn()` on a separate line is more readable, but you can also do `fn[Math.floor(Math.random() * fns.length)]();` without using an unnecessary variable.

Comment: This answers the question! Just wondering- How would I clear this interval?

Answer (score 0):

Add each functionname to an array, with numerical key indexing.  Then, randomly generate a number between the lower and upper index and use a control structure to repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (see http://jsfiddle.net/w6sdc/):

```
/* A few functions */
var a = function() {
    alert("A");
}

var b = function() {
    alert("B");
}

var c = function() {
    alert("C");
}

/* Add the functions to an array */
var funcs = [a, b, c];

/* Select a random array index */
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 0;

/* Call the function at that index */
funcs[i]();
```

Wrapping the index selection and the function call in a `setInterval` should be straight forward from this point.